# Func<Task> disguised as Action

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection

### The problem

I have the following code:

```cs
Action function = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;
```

The problem with this code is that even though technically speaking it is an async delegate (one that can be `awaited`) I cannot await it. In other words, the above could be written equivalently as

```cs
Func<Task> function = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;
```

The latter can be awaited, while the former cannot, even though this is the same method internally. Obviously, this is a contrived example, in my use case more complex code resides in a more complex codebase and it is not easy to spot all misusages.

### The question

**Can I check the actual type of `function` at runtime and cast it to the correct one?**

#### What I tried

Code below only throws if I declare `function` as `Func<Task>` (aka does not work as I expect it to)

```cs
Action function = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;
if (function.GetMethodInfo().ReturnType.IsEquivalentTo(typeof(Task)))
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Code below does not even compile

```cs
Action function = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;
if (function is Func<Task> func)
{
    
}
```

Comment: *Code below does not even compile* ... [yes, it does](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1dXSPS) .. please show what does not compile ... if you *declare `function` as `Func<Task>`* then where is the problem? the type of `function` is well known then

Comment: Now it make sens

Comment: I don't think if you can catch such thing ... it is same story if you would put async call without await into non async method  `void Method() {  MethodAsync(); }` but at least in such case you have compiler warning

Comment: *"technically speaking it is an async delegate (one that can be awaited)"* -- Technically speaking it is an [`async void`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming") delegate. `async void` methods are `async` methods that return `void`, which obviously can't be awaited.

Comment: [Here is generated code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5lqZwB0ASgKYBmANuQMYAuAlgPYB2+SBAzJjOgGF0Ab2TpxmXlAAs6ALIAKAJQixE9Vn6UArm0as2cdAF5MADnTKTAPkwBOdABVyAZwYBBFwE89yzuo04LV19dn5TZzd/CQBfNXF4zFlIhmVE0SQAiRTPHzo/RLjMiUSoCygANidXD29fJXTEjQdK4gEWAFsAB1oGcmBK6PEi9WQYoA=) as you can see you can do nothing about this ...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias what I meant here was analogous to inheritance - even though Cat instance is assigned to an Animal-typed variable, it is still a Cat. But after all, it seems Actions and Func's are not connected by this kind of relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even though this is the same method internally.

It's not, though.

The delegate is compiled into a method, sure, but the type of that method *is determined by what it's assigned to*. If it's assigned to `Func<Task>`, then it's a `Task`-returning method. If it's assigned to `Action`, then it's a `void`-returning method.

So, `check the actual type of function at runtime` isn't going to work; runtime is too late.

Instead, you need a compile-time check. And good news: there are analyzers that should catch this. E.g., [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AsyncVoidLambda.html) or [Roslyn analyzers](https://roslyn-analyzers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/analyzers-info/async/avoid-async-void-methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

##### Checking the type of the delegate at runtime

Does calling `.GetType()` help?

> Code below does not even compile
>
> ```cs
> Action function = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;
> if (function is Func<Task> func)
> {
>    
> }
> ```

This will compile and run

```cs
Action function = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;
if (function.GetType() == typeof(Func<Task>))
{
    // not reachable
}
```

At runtime

```cs
Action function1 = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;
Func<Task> function2 = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;

var b = function1.GetType() == typeof(Action); // true
b = function1.GetType() == typeof(Func<Task>); // false
b = function2.GetType() == typeof(Action); // false
b = function2.GetType() == typeof(Func<Task>); // true
```

##### Some Useful Extensions

```cs
public static bool IsAction(this MulticastDelegate @delegate) =>
    @delegate.GetType() == typeof(Action);

public static bool ReturnsTask(this MulticastDelegate @delegate) =>
    @delegate.GetType() == typeof(Func<Task>);

public static bool ReturnsTask<T>(this MulticastDelegate @delegate) =>
    @delegate.GetType() == typeof(Func<Task<T>>);
```

Example Usage

```cs
var function = async () => await Task.FromResult(true);
var b = function.IsAction(); // false
b = function.ReturnsTask(); // false
b = function.ReturnsTask<string>(); // false
b = function.ReturnsTask<bool>(); // true
if (b)
{
    // possible to await
    await function?.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I was looking for something that would say `function1.GetType() == typeof(Func<Task>)` is `true`. Apparently, it is impossible.